# Problem pulling json content with variable url

Tags: javascript, json, clipboard

I hope someone can help me out with this one

My question is why does this code do exactly what I need?

```
var wfComponent;
fetch("https://nube-components.netlify.app/navbar01.json")
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((data) => (wfComponent = data))
  .then(() => console.log(wfComponent));

document.addEventListener("copy", function (e) {
  e.clipboardData.setData("application/json", wfComponent);
  e.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("navbar01").onclick = function () {
  document.execCommand("copy");
};
```

And this one does not do the copy to clipboard part?

```
$(".button.copy-button").on("click", function () {
  let tag = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(tag);

  var wfComponent;
  fetch("https://nube-components.netlify.app/" + tag + ".json")
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((data) => (wfComponent = data))
    .then(() => console.log(wfComponent));

  document.addEventListener("copy", function (e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("application/json", wfComponent);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  document.getElementById(tag).onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  };
});
```

Now as you can see what I need is to "automate" that JSON location and target button part where I need each button to target a different URL. So I am now lost in this area where I manage to pull that id and apply it to the URL but the content does not get copied to the clipboard.

I am not a JS expert at all so please feel free to pinpoint anything I might be doing wrong or any ways to do this completely differently

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you use addEventListener inside the other. But either way, there is another (possibly hacky) way to achieve this.

```js
$(".copy-button").on("click", function(e) {
  let tag = $(this).attr("id");
  fetch("https://nube-components.netlify.app/" + tag + ".json")
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((data) => (wfComponent = data))
    .then(() => {
      let copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
      document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
      copyFrom.textContent = wfComponent;
      copyFrom.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      copyFrom.remove();
      console.log('COPIED!');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="navbar01" class="copy-button">copy navbar01</button>

<button id="navbar02" class="copy-button">copy navbar02</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer and extra info on what I did wrong. Unfortunately, this one does not seem to solve the issue, this time around I get a message that my clipboard is empty after hitting the button.

Comment: It works for me on 4 different browsers

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I am doing it in Webflow but it should work anyway since there is no difference at all. And I agree completely, when I run the snippet here it seems to be able to copy the json. Any chance you have a solution that is more similar to what I had before? Since that first snippet worked everytime